# How to make wallpapers work in Lubuntu with two monitors?

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, desktop-background, lxqt

I hope this is allowed to ask, since its Lubuntu what I am using.

When I connect to a second monitor, the wallpaper gets stretched across both screen, and all the different settings in the desktop menu all apply to both screens as it would be just one. I would like to either have both monitors just show each the wallpaper like on one screen or have one screen just wothout a wallaper and have it one the other normally.

## Edits

1. I am using release 19.10

Comment: I only want the panel on my main screen (laptop in that case) but tbh I dont care if it has to be on both, if it solves my wallpaper issue. Same for the icons. I just want the wallpaper somewhere in one piece, not stretched across both screens in any way.

Comment: Your release details would have helped (*and yes Lubuntu is an official flavor thus your question is on-topic on any Ubuntu site, IRC, or lubuntu.me etc*).  A team member (*HmollerCl*) wrote a script https://phab.lubuntu.me/T54 https://code.launchpad.net/~hmollercl/stitchwp/+git/stitchwp https://forum.lxqt.org/t/wallpaper-in-multiple-monitor-workaround/387 ) which was attempted to be pushed upstream alas.. It works on all LXQt releases of Lubuntu

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention I use 19.10, I added it to my question. I downloaded the script and run it, but it didnt work, in `/home/ben/.config/pcmanfm-qt/lxqt` is no new wallpaper file generated. I have to check later if I can figure out why. - Nevermind, I figured it out. In `Desktop Preferences` the wallpaper mode has to be `Stretch to fill the entire screen`, or it wont work. Thank you!

Comment: Can I suggest you write your own answer in detail (where you got it, what you did etc).  When Hans put it together a number of us grabbed & tested it as requested, but that was some time ago for me (and before 19.10, so it may have changed slightly)

Comment: Just wrote it, hope it is comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here is what I did to get what I want

### 1. Download stitchWP (Hans P. Möller)

Either from this website [code.launchpad.net/~hmollercl/stitchwp/+git/stitchwp](https://code.launchpad.net/~hmollercl/stitchwp/+git/stitchwp) or by directly running `git clone https://git.launchpad.net/~hmollercl/stitchwp` in your terminal. @guiverc gave this tip!

### 2. Select Wallpaper

Make sure you have selected your wallpaper of choice, also make sure that **Wallpaper mode** is set to **Stretch to fill the entire screen**.

### 3. Run the script

`cd` into the downloaded folder and execute it with `./stitchWP.sh`. Sometimes it takes a couple seconds if the image is huge, so be patient.