# Is it possible to have a different background on mutliple displays-Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, desktop-background, lxqt

I am a casual Linux user here, so my knowledge is limited.

The default Lubuntu background is stretching itself across both of my displays. I followed the directions to install `stitchwp` here: [How to make wallpapers work in Lubuntu with two monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211641/how-to-make-wallpapers-work-in-lubuntu-with-two-monitors), and it appeared to install `stitchwp`. The results seem similar to before though. It still does not allow me to have one background image on each display, nor can I have two different images.

Ideally, I'd like the same default Lubuntu background image correctly shown on each display.
I have Lubuntu 20.04.3 installed on a virtual box 6.1.28.

Is there an easy solution to have one desktop background image on each monitor, so that there isn't any stretching?

It would be nice if there was an option in Desktop Preferences that read something like: Center on each separate display/stretch to fit on each display. Or have "Display 1 background image -select" and "Display 2 background image-select".  [image: Desktop Preferences Capture]

Comment: Yes; a Lubuntu *dev* created a script to allow that to be accomplished many releases ago (found in the link you provided in my comments).. Lubuntu's LXQt allows for that already on later releases, eg. the manual shows https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.5/desktop.html where you'll note a "*Individual wallpaper for each monitor*" checkbox, but that's not available with the LXQt used by 20.04 (ie. [the manual for 20.04 doesn't include references to those options](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.5/desktop.html)).  I'll have to return later & see if I can provide more

Comment: So is this desktop dual monitor feature something that will have to be implemented in some future update? If so, is it a matter of waiting weeks or months?  Or is this a matter of switching desktop environments?

Comment: It's already available (and was available in 21.04; I forget if it was in 20.10 too) - thus why it's in the *stable* release of the manual; it's just not available in *focal* or 20.04, and you'll get the feature only when you upgrade to a later release. Security fixes only are back-ported; you're already using the latest LXQt possible on the then available Qt5 5.12.8 LTS (*subsequent releases of Qt5 were non-LTS*) so only used in non-LTS releases of Lubuntu/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Studio (*which share the same Qt5 libs found in Ubuntu repositories*).

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late answer, but I modified Hans Möller's [stitchWP.sh](https://github.com/hmollercl/stitchWP/blob/master/stitchWP.sh) script to work be able to specify a different image wallpaper per monitor. I uploaded [here](https://gist.github.com/hydren/e5ce82a79c2a4c4203491534613a6915). I also made a [zenity script](https://gist.github.com/hydren/4896fd22c0a4ef0fc3131b62c2b4c2e5) to provide a silly dialog to select image per monitor.